# Java unknown output

Tags: java

Soo this problem involves me rolling a pair of dice and estimate the probability that the first roll is a losing roll (2, 3, or 12).

output is the count of rolls that were losers (2,3, or 12) and calculated probability (count/N)

```
   public static void main(String [] args){
      int N1 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1); 
      int N2 = (int) (Math.random()*6 + 1); 
      int count = N1 + N2; 
           for (int i = 0; i<=1; i++)
          if (count==2 || count = 3 || count == 12)
```

I just don't seem to know what to do get the output......  This is my attempt

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag as such.

Comment: You're not supposed to delete questions when they've been answered.  The whole point of upvoting and accepting answers is so other people can learn from these questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you will want to roll the dice N times (where N is some large number) and count the number of times that it was a loser, correct?

So you will need to store in memory the total number of rolls, and the number of losing rolls.  You can store those in `int` variables.

An `int` variable can be incremented using the `++` operator.

```
int rolls = 0;
rolls++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int rolls = 0;
rolls = rolls + 1;
```

You also don't want to call your `main` function a million times, so you can set the upper limit of your loop to the amount of rolls you want to have.

To calculate the probability, you will want to use `float`s rather than `int`s - you can cast an `int` to a `float` like this:

```
int a = 10;
float b = (float) a;
```

Finally, if you want to see your output via standard out, use `System.out.println()`.  The argument to the `println()` function should be whatever you want to output.

Since this sounds like homework, I'm avoiding writing much code for now.  Let me know if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get output from a command-line app (like you are writing) is to use `System.out.println(...)`.  For example:

```
int digits = 5;
System.out.println("Hello world");
System.out.println("I have " + digits + " fingers");
```

This should be enough of a hint for you to make progress.